# country convert to continent

Tags: python, function

```
def country_to_continent(country_name):
    country_alpha2 = pc.country_name_to_country_alpha2(country_name)
    country_continent_code = pc.country_alpha2_to_continent_code(country_alpha2)
    country_continent_name = pc.convert_continent_code_to_continent_name(country_continent_code)
    return country_continent_name
countries = list(df['country'])

[country_to_continent(country)for country in countries]
```

```
def country_to_continent(country_name):
    country_alpha2 = pc.country_name_to_country_alpha2(country_name)
    country_continent_code = pc.country_alpha2_to_continent_code(country_alpha2)
    country_continent_name = pc.convert_continent_code_to_continent_name(country_continent_code)
    return country_continent_name

country_name = list(df['country'])
country_to_continent(country_name)
```

Acutually I can't get it why my second one is wrong but the first one is right . and get unhashable error

Comment: Please provide more information about what exactly you are trying to do and what error you are facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second snippet, you pass list of `countries` to `country_to_continent` function, which according to the first example, receives a single `country` as a parameter.

If you want to convert the whole column in your Dataframe, try instead:

```
print(df["country"].apply(lambda x: country_to_continent(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `unhashable type` error in the second one because your function is assuming that the parameter passed to it is a `country_name` and not a `list` of `country_name`.

When you do this
`[country_to_continent(country)for country in countries]`, you are passing every element of `countries` one by one to your function.

However, when you say

```
country_name = list(df['country'])
country_to_continent(country_name)
```

You pass the entire list in one go to your function, which results in that error.