# How to convert a list of countries into their corresponding continents using pycountry_convert?

Tags: python, pycountry-convert

I am trying to convert the list of countries in my dataset into their corresponding continents . I am using this code for help link:
[country convert to continent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61300446/country-convert-to-continent)

but i got error when try to execute the code given above :

" KeyError: "Invalid Country Alpha-2 code: 'AQ'"   "

Here is my code :

```
import pycountry_convert as pc

def country_to_continent(country_name):
    country_alpha2 = pc.country_name_to_country_alpha2(country_name)
    country_continent_code = pc.country_alpha2_to_continent_code(country_alpha2)
    country_continent_name = pc.convert_continent_code_to_continent_name(country_continent_code)
    return country_continent_name
countries = list(temp['Area'])

[country_to_continent(country)for country in countries]
```

temp is the name of my dataset

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset?

Comment: yes sure please use this link for the dataset    [link](https://github.com/Z-Unlocked/Unlocked_Challenge_1/blob/main/temperature_change_data_11-29-2021.csv)

Answer (score 0):

The error indicated is caused by the translation from country name to alpha2 code. In the lib source files AQ (the offical code) is missing (under windows in `AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pycountry_convert\convert_country_alpha2_to_continent_code.py` I added `'AQ': 'AN',` on line 19).

However, there some error after that cause by the naming of some countries (the dataset does not claim those are countries but rather areas):

- `Belgium-Luxembourg`: not a country
- `Bolivia (Plurinational State of)`: Just called `Bolivia` by the lib
- `Channel Islands`: Not a country
- `China, Hong Kong SAR`: Just `Hong Kong`
- `China, Macao SAR`: Just `Macao`
- `China, mainland`: Not sure why there is `China` as well as this.
- `China, Taiwan Province of`: Just `Taiwan`

I'll stop here since you get the drift. Some dataset cleeanup necessary, after that it works.

Comment: @ white thank you so much for the answer, actually I am very beginner at python and data wrangling could you please elaborate the answer , will be highly obliged as I am new in python. Thanks and regards

Comment: For which part do you require further explanation and which parts are clear so far?

Comment: Thanks Mr White, as you stated that some dataset cleanup is necessary, mean my dataset country column is not clean as per alpha code or ISO , so should i clean this column according to alpha code?

Comment: What I did was fix the first issue, then I tried to run it to see which country did cause an error, went to the module source file (`Python310\Lib\site-packages\pycountry\databases\iso3166.json`) to check what they called the country instead and adjusted it in the dataset. Rinse and repeat.